# How to send right model

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

I send model with ajax on server with post request.

I have next model and a controller that has a method of fasting.

```
 public class TestDto: BaseDto
{
    [Required]
    public ProductGalleryDto GalleryProduct { get; set; }

    public int? RetailPriceEur { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? AmountSpc { get; set; }

    public bool? PrizeSent { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsParticipant { get; internal set; }
}

public override IActionResult Post([FromBody] TestDto item)
        {
            if (!IsAdmin)
                return BadRequest(ApiErrorCodes.InsufficientPriveleges);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ApiErrorCodes.RequiredFieldsMissing, ModelState.Keys.FirstOrDefault());
 }
```

JS:

```
var object = JSON.stringify({
        createddate: startdate,
        retailpriceeur: price,
        amountspc: spobicoinprice,
        prizesent: false,
        expirationdate: expirationdate,
        comment: comment,
        productgalleryid: productgalleryDto
    });

    $.ajax({
        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('authToken') },
        url: "/api/testapi/",
        method: "post",
        data: object,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
```

Fields in js are also present in the model
Actual: model is not valid. 
How me fix that? Please, help

Comment: You are trying to send an object with stringified data in it: `{ object }` <--

Comment: `object` is a string, and you're wrapping it in `{ }`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @briosheje Sealed, fixed, the question remains the same. How to inject an object into a model that accepts the product ID

Comment: @ChrisG Sealed, fixed, the question remains the same. How to inject an object into a model that accepts the product ID

Comment: @AndrewStark that's rather a C# issue, you should show all the code related to .NET. Usually, you need a deserializer on server side.

Comment: @briosheje Added, you can take a look

Comment: There is no way it can actually work. I usually use `DataContract` and `DataMember` for serialization in C#. In any case, though, property names are not case insensitive, your model right now has no chances to work at all. Please refer to a basic tutorial on how to correctly setup your environment to actually acquire values, test it and debug it if necessary, right now, in my opinion, the question is just too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Shroud send an object not JSON string in ajax request as this example :

```html
 var person = new Object();  
             person.name = "name";  
             person.surname = "surname";
             $.ajax({  
                 url: 'http://localhost:3413/api/person',  
                 type: 'POST',   
                 data: person,  
                 success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {  
                     console.log(data);  
                 },  
                 error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                     console.log('Error in Operation');  
                 }  
             });
```

Comment: Can you fix/reformat your answer so that it's easier to understand? I'm not sure what you're trying to say.